# VueJS - How to tell vue about external changes in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom

I am currently working on a larger web application that is based on MVC Razor Pages.
For future components we want to use VueJS.
Now i have the following problem:
Parts of my Page get loaded and rendered then the VueJs instance attaches itself to the root element.
After a few (or a few more) seconds further data is retrieved and additional HTML-Snippets are injected into the DOM. Now this new injected HTML-Snippets do contain tags for some of our vue components, but they get injected by MVC Razor. 
The root VueJS instance seems not no notice this changes in the DOM. Therefore the vue component tags in the new HTML do not get used/hooked by VueJS.

While I do understand the basic problem, I wonder whether there is a good workaround.
We can not just update complete parts of our web app to VueJS - they are to big and to legacy. But if there is no workaround for VueJS to detect those external DOM changes It will become hard to migrate our web app...

Thanks for every response in advance,
mitras2

Comment: maybe if you can intervene when those snippets get injected, you could apply something like a `Vue.compile(...)` on them, then obtain your root Vue object and somehow connect the compiled result into it... I'm not too sure about specifics, just an idea